# How to enforce URI segments to Kohana pagination after the page URI segment?

Tags: model-view-controller, pagination, kohana

I'm using Kohana's pagination library and it lets you specify the parameter *uri_segment* at initialization.

When it generates the pages links, they will have that *uri_segment* you specified, and after that, the page link. Let's say: `/some/uri/segments/6` where 6 is the page.

Now, that enforces the page number to be the last uri segment. What if your URI schema needs to have more segments after the page, which is my case, as I'm making a search controller that can have a variable amount of optional search parameters, but as the page number is not optionalm it has to be at the beginning.

Thanks!

PS: hey there's no *uri* or *uri-segment* tags, they might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
by using the parameter *base_url*, you can specify all the URI segments, and in *uri_segment* (a number) you specify which one of those is to be replaced by the page number.